# Flutter Staggered Grid View Pin tiles

Tags: flutter, staggered-gridview

I'm using a staggered grid (flutter staggered grid view package) to display notes. It all works fine but I can't find any information on pinning tiles, like 'google keep' notes.
The notes are stored in a database (sqlite) and it's no problem to add a column (pinned), but how do I tell the staggered grid view widget to keep pinned notes at the top and preferably separate from the other notes? ideally I would like to add the "pinned" and "others" text as well.

[pinned note example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H64tH.png)

Answer (score 0):

don't do it in just one staggeredGrid, make them 2 separated grids, once remove and add to different grids

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have now done it in 2 separate grids, thank you for your help. I was wondering if there was an even easier way, like a property I could use, but it's done now   :-)